# override selectedSegmentIndex

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol, setter

I have a subclass of `UISegmentedControl` and want to catch a event of selecting segment.

I overrided `selectedSegmentIndex` and use `didSet` but it is not invoked and value is changed without calling `didSet`.

```
class SLSegmentControl: UISegmentedControl {
    override var selectedSegmentIndex: Int {
        didSet {
            print(selectedSegmentIndex)
        }
    }
```

If I set

```
isMomentary = true
```

the `didSet` is invoked with value `-1` whichever segment selected.

Currently I'm using `addTarget` to catch this event. However this will be disabled once outside of this class adds Target to this class, so I want to avoid to use this.

```
addTarget(self, action: #selector(didSegmentSelect(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
```

As long as I remember it worked in `objective-c` but not working in `swift 3`. Am I missing something?

I can track user interaction with adding observer to `selectedSegmentIndex`.

Comment: Why aren't you just overriding the delegate methods for the UISegmentedControl in the subclass? Don't understand why you are trying to access `selectedSegmentIndex` directly like that.

Comment: @MikeJSChoi 'UISegmentedControl' doesn't have any protocol. https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol

Comment: my bad! Have you tried `IBAction`-ing it with `indexChanged`?

Comment: That was what I did with addTarget. But if I do so, it can be easily broken by adding target outside of the class. I think using observer is the only way here. Just want to know why didSet is not invoked.

Comment: When I build a component like this, I'm trying to keep the class very generic as much as possible, so I or someone who use this class can use all the things like adding listener. I believe it is a good coding habit.

Answer (score 1):

If I set

```
isMomentary = true
```

the didSet is invoked with value -1 whichever segment selected.

If you set `isMomentary = true` then your segmented control will act more like a horizontal stackview of buttons and upon any tapping it will trigger a `valueChanged` callback with the correct index, but then immediately set it to `noSegment` ie `-1`.

With `isMomentary = true` if you tap on a button, it gets highlighted then goes back to its **normal** state. It doesn't have a selected state. Normally it's not what you want. It's just a convenience to horizontal stackview of buttons. It's a bit counter intuitive I'd say.